# Chrome bypasses MVC4 login method

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, owin, logout

So I am working on an application where I try to auto log off the user when they close the broswer.

Here is what I have in my logOff method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{ 
  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This works good for IE, FireFox, etc.. It doesn't work for Chrome. When I close the google chrome tab and open a new one up to the same webpage, I am able to hit it without logging back in.

Thoughts, suggestions. I am sitting at a road block right now trying to get this to work.